# Accessing pointer to a polymorphic value with C_PTR

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran function which compiled with previous versions of Intel Fortran Compiler (ifort), but is rejected by more recent versions (2021.6.0), and I hope to fix it. This function accepts a `class(*)`, and passes its address and length to a C function:

```
!> Send an arbitrary scalar object.
function SendObject(my,obj) result(ok)
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none
    class(Socket) :: my
    class(*), target, intent(in)  :: obj

    type(c_ptr)       :: ptr
    integer(c_size_t) :: len

    ptr = c_loc(obj)
    len = c_sizeof(obj)
    ok = my%SendData(ptr,len)

end function
```

ifort now emits an error:

```
error #9023: The argument to C_LOC must not be polymorphic.   [OBJ]
ptr = c_loc(obj)
```

While this function is polymorphic, in practice it is used only for a few simple structs containing scalars.

What is the best way to get this function "working" again, as well as it worked with previous compilers? I just need to get a C pointer to `obj`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What ezactly can you assune about what is passed? Are the possible dynamic types known in advance?

Comment: Yes, I believe them all to be simple structs containing exclusively scalars.

Comment: That is not the point. Do you know which actual types are they? Can you determine (name, not describe) some common subset from which they are derived?

Comment: Yes I can enumerate all of the concrete types. Some example types which are sent through the socket include`REAL(KIND=8)`, `INTEGER(KIND=4)`, and an aggregate structure containing a `CHARACTER(4)` and an `INTEGER(4)`

Comment: So you are also sending raw basic types, not only structs? Anyway, if you do know the types, you can use `select type` type guards as you were also suggested at https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/accessing-address-of-a-polymorphic-value-with-c-ptr/4290 the other option with `type(*)` also came to my mind but I do not remember the details and had no time to study them.

Comment: By the way, by naming I meant naming the actual structs, not the members. That is necessary for the `select type` solution. You need to know the exact struct types that are allowed and have acceess to their definitions (or just redefine them locally if they are `bind(C)`).

Comment: BTW, I would probably suggest asking at the discourse group or here and wait if you get an answer and if not, trying the other option. Asking at both at the same time is problematic as answerers here cannot really just re-use material someone suggested at the Discourse group. Basically, there is no point answering for me now, because I would mostly just repeat what others already posted there.

Comment: As for why it is not working the error message is very clear "The argument to C_LOC must not be polymorphic". So if you want a solution you will either have to use some non-standard Fortran if you want to cover all cases, or use select type as Vladamir suggests and keep the number of cases limited. As to why it worked in earlier compilers it may well have been a bug in a compiler that let it through.